# How do I edit a Java-Desktop menu item?

Tags: solaris-10

I need to edit a menu item for all users in the Launch menu of Java Desktop on a system running Solaris 10.  I need to set the launcher to a different executable.  I have followed the steps in the Java Desktop Administration Guide.  I can set the launcher to the correct file but cannot find an option to save the change.  Is there a way to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Launch Menu/Applications, items are stored in /usr/share/applications in .desktop files.  One file per Launcher.  You can manually edit these files.  The launcher commands are in there near the bottom.

For Launchers outside of Applications, I'm actually trying to discover how those are controlled.  I need to remove a launcher under Launch Menu/Preferences